# TYPO3 Mask_Export: Any way I can export my mask elements without deleting the content?

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, tx-mask

I'm currently working on a TYPO3 Project and used the [mask](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/mask/) extension for the first time. I created a lot of elements, used them on the site and filled them with content. I just read in the manual that the mask extension itself causes some performance problems which i didn't knew about..

I installed the [mask_export](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/mask_export/) extension to prevent those, but now my content is gone.. I tried to just tell my TYPO3 to use the new content element but my contents ist still not displayed in it.

Is there any way I can use the mask_export extension in a running project without deleting my content?

Answer (score 0):

If You use `ext:mask_export` your defined mask elements are exported in a new extension.
While the elements are exported they were renamed acording to the new extension name.
If you now deactivate mask and enable your new extension, your existing content (`tt_content`-records) have the wrong `CType` (there is no rendering definition).

Solution:
Reenable mask, deactivate your new extension and build a test-page with all content elements, then disable mask and enable your extension and build all content elments again (additionally). Now you can do a SQL-query (`SELECT CType FROM tt_content WHERE pid=123`) to identify the used CTypes and do database wide replacements.

Be aware, that the extension name may be used in other places (e.g. prefix for tables or fields). This needs to be fixed too.

**Conclusion:**
It's a bad idea to replace mask after content is inserted, as it generates a lot of manual work in the database.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'll try this later. Can you tell me how bad the performance issues will be? Is it that big of a deal? Do you think it is better to try your solution and maybe having to manually replace every content element or stick with the mask extension without exporting it?

Comment: I have no numbers, we have one installation where we thougt to replace mask with the exported function later. but as we noticed the amount we stayed with mask in the production system. If you have a high performance site with heavy load it might be noticable, but remember: TYPO3 does a lot of caching where you will not notice anything (except if the cache needs to be rebuild or if you avoid cache)